# SQL Server Management Studio edit timeout

Tags: timeout, ssms, edit

I am trying to run a query to edit records in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and keep getting the error: 
"SQL Execution Error.
Error Message: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

I have set the following:
Execution Time-out: 0
Set Lock Timeout: -1
Transaction time-out after: 65535

The message appears at about 30 seconds....

Answer (score 0):

There are locks on the database you are trying to change.  You need to first remove the locks, then you can execute your change.